# Git How to tag a remote branch

Tags: git

I'm trying to create a script that will loop through all the branches on our server and archive old branches.

To get the list of branches I'm using the command

```
git branch -r
```

I then want to tag each branch, so inside a foreach loop

```
git tag archive/branchname branchname
```

However when I run the `tag` command I get an error

> error: branch 'branchname' not found

I've also tried with

```
git tag archive/branchname origin/branchname
```

and get the same error, except this time its origin/branchname not found

tldr;

**How can I tag a branch on remote?**

Comment: Could you double check the branchname exists? I tested on my env and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to tag a remote remote branch, as long as `git branch -avv` shows you:

```
remotes/origin/abranch
```

I tested `git tag archive/aTag origin/aBranch` (lightweight tag) successfully, as long as a tag "archive" itself did not exist already.